# Query XML Attribute values in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, where-clause

I have the following xml Data in an XML column

```
<LoyaltyInfo ServerDate="2056-12-12">
  <Accounts>
    <Acc ID="1" Value="2.750" UpToDate="2014-05-13 18:38:00" />
    <Acc ID="2" Value="2.750" UpToDate="2014-05-13 18:38:00" />
    <Acc ID="3" Value="141.06" UpToDate="2014-05-22 12:53:00" />
    <Acc ID="6" Value="924.42" UpToDate="2014-06-01 16:53:00" />
    <Acc ID="7" Value="2895" UpToDate="2014-05-13 18:38:00" />
 </Accounts>
</LoyaltyInfo>
```

I want to write an SQL query to say WHERE  Acc ID = x and in the same row Acc Value = y

Ive tried the following but i get errors

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TableName
    WHERE xmlData.exist('/LoyaltyInfo/Accounts/Acc[@ID="20"]') = 1 
    AND xmlData.value('/LoyaltyInfo/Accounts/Acc/@Value','integer') = 0

SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE xmlData.exist('/LoyaltyInfo/Accounts/Acc[@ID="20"]') = 1 
AND   xmlData.value('/LoyaltyInfo/Accounts/Acc[@Value]','integer') = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query using `fn.min()` function to emulate `AND` operator:

```
select *
FROM T
WHERE xmldata.value('fn:min((LoyaltyInfo/Accounts/Acc/@ID="3",
              LoyaltyInfo/Accounts/Acc/@Value="141.06"))','bit')=CAST(1 as bit)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b3d5/40)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone else looking in the future

For 1 condition

```
select xmldata.query('for $loyaltyinfo in /LoyaltyInfo/Accounts                          
let $id :=$loyaltyinfo/Acc/@ID
let $value := $loyaltyinfo/Acc/@Value
where $id = "19" and $value = "141.06"
return $loyaltyinfo
') as [Valid Data]
FROM T
```

For 2 conditions

```
select xmldata.query('for $loyaltyinfo in /LoyaltyInfo/Accounts                          
let $id :=$loyaltyinfo/Acc/@ID
let $value := $loyaltyinfo/Acc/@Value
where ($id = "19" and $value = "141.06") and ($id = "20" and $value = "0.00")
return $loyaltyinfo
') as [Valid Data]
FROM T
```